# vectorising the eval(parse(text)) function

Tags: r, vector, eval

I have a problem in R with the funciont eval.parent...
Let's take a data.table foo like

```
Value  Command
NA     "is.na(foo$Value)"
NA     "foo$Value>1"
```

I want to create a third column named *App_command* in which I have the result of the application of the command in the column *Command*.

I have tried with the line

```
foo<-foo[,App_command:=eval.parent(parse(text=foo$Command))]
```

but the output is

```
Value  Command               App_command
NA     "is.na(foo$Value)"    NA
NA     "foo$Value>1"         NA
```

I have also tried to switch the two rows, i.e. applying the command to de table

```
Value  Command            
NA     "foo$Value>1"       
NA     "is.na(foo$Value)"
```

and the result is

```
Value  Command              App_command
NA     "foo$Value>1"        TRUE 
NA     "is.na(foo$Value)"   TRUE
```

the parse function's output is

```
expression(foo$Value>1,is.na(foo$Value))
```

so I think that the eval.parent function, applied to a expression with more than 1 argument, just evaluate the last argument. Is there any method, without the use of for cycle, maybe through sapply and co., which could make the eval.parent work?
Thank you!

Comment: Guess that your desired output is `c(TRUE,NA)` on the first example. Am I right? If so, I think your table is not well designed. The first command acts on an entire vector (`foo$Value`), while it seems to me that you want it to act only on `foo$Value[[1]]`. No idea how you got some data structure, but I think you should revisit your pipeline.

Comment: @nicola Was not addressed to you. I like to have data that is directly "ready to use" when someone asks a question. Sort of "I help you, so you help me".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several issues here:

first of all `foo$Value` is a vector of length two:

```
eval.parent(parse(text="is.na(foo$Value)"))
```

outputs a vector of length two:

```
TRUE TRUE
```

another example:

```
a <- c(1, NA)
eval.parent(parse(text="is.na(a)"))
#FALSE TRUE
```

now you would like to vectorize eval.parent, this can be done by:

```
eval_vec = Vectorize(eval.parent, vectorize.args = "expr")

eval_vec(parse(text = foo$Command))
#    [,1] [,2]
[1,] TRUE   NA
[2,] TRUE   NA
```

first column contains evaluation on `"is.na(foo$Value)"` and the second on `"foo$Value>1"`

the diagonal of this matrix is what I think you are looking for (evaluation of first expression on first element and so on):

```
diag(eval_vec(parse(text = foo$Command)))

library(data.table)
foo[,App_command:=diag(eval_vec(parse(text=foo$Command)))]
foo
   Value          Command App_command
1:    NA is.na(foo$Value)        TRUE
2:    NA      foo$Value>1          NA
```

data:

```
foo <- read.table(text = "Value  Command
NA     is.na(foo$Value)
NA     foo$Value>1", header = TRUE)

foo$Command <- as.character(foo$Command)

library(data.table)

foo <- as.data.table(foo)
```